# Please don't scroll the notification bar / top banner

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, notifications, top-bar

I'm bothered by the change in the notification bar from what I'm looking at right now on meta.stackexchange to what I see today on Stack Overflow. I don't want the top bar to follow me after I start to scroll.

It's attention-grabbing, with the bright red and green alerts, and these show up on every page I open if I'm working on a challenging question (and don't want to check my inbox/reputation first).

It also takes reading real estate away, and the links (Questions, Jobs, and Tags) are very off-track once I'm working on a question. I don't need super-fast access to the search bar.

Seeing the change on one Stack Exchange site makes me concerned it's an experiment being considered for the whole network.

Comment: [We're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation)

Comment: Yay! thanks!  (Incidentally, for less-responsive-to-users sites like nytimes.com, I've found custom adblock rules helpful to remove top banners that aim to keep users on-site at the expense of on-task: trending/recommended/hot/etc.)

Comment: The lakasin dessert

Comment: Shouldn't @animuson's comment be posted as the answer to this question?